# IE7: li's behaving badly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6LBV/1/

IE7 is giving me and my a website a ton of grief. As much as I would like to meet Microsoft down a dark alley and get this sorted once and for all, I'm hoping one of you can help.

IE7 is hurting my `li` tags in two ways, the first by disrespecting their `width:auto;` property and instead of expanding to the width of the widest `li`, each `li` shrivels down to the size of its own copy plus padding.

As can be seen here:

[image: curse you IE7]

Next up, IE7 be disrespecting my jQuery. I have a function which animates the `ul` sliding down when you hover over each parent `li`. However IE7 for some reason (I believe it has to do with `display: none`) underestimates the width of my `ul` during animation and pops into the correct width once it is finished.

As can be seen here:

[image: Shuttupa your face, you gotsa no respect]

So here is the markup for my dropdown:

```
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="grid_16">
        <div id="breadcrumbs">
            <a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps" id="home"></a>
            <ul id="parent" class="grid_15 omega">
            <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/">Personal and people development </a><ul class="child"><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/getting-started/">Getting started</a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/">Communication</a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/health-safety-and-security/">Health, Safety and Security</a></li><li class="active" ><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/">Personal and people development </a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/quality/">Quality</a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/equality-diversity-and-rights/">Equality, diversity and rights </a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/clinical-skills/">Clinical skills</a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/additional-material/">Additional material</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#">Select a topic</a><ul class="child"><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/performance-appraisal/">Performance appraisal </a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/personal-development-planning/">Personal development planning</a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/learning-and-development-opportunities/">Learning and development opportunities </a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/lifelong-learning/">Lifelong learning </a></li><li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/reflection/">Reflection</a></li></ul></li>                         </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="supplements" class="grid_16">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#" class="button alpha"><img src="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/library/images/book-icon.png" alt="book icon">View competencies checklist</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" class="button alpha bold"><img src="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/library/images/rcn-icon.png" alt="rcn icon">Join the RCN</a>

            <a href="#" class="button omega">Reasons to joins</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css to boot:

```
#breadcrumbs {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 39px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid;
    border-left: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-right: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#breadcrumbs ul {
    list-style: none; 
    list-style-image: none; 
    margin: 0;
}

#breadcrumbs #home{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 39px;
    width: 54px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(library/images/home_icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 19px center;   
    text-indent: -999em;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent {
    display: block;
    height: 39px;
    float: right;
    right: 3px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f38630;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li {
    position: relative;
    height: 39px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 1px; /* required to fix Opera bug */
    padding: 0 47px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(library/images/breadcrumb_seperator.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    line-height: 39px;
    zoom: 1;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li a {
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:900;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #cf7229;
}

#breadcrumbs ul li a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li:first-child ul {
    left: -5px;
}
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9998;
    left: -28px;
    top: 42px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-left: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-right: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    list-style-position: outside;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    display:none;
}

.no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background-image: url(library/images/arrow-icon.png);
    background-position: -25px 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #738793;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 26px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    zoom: 1;
    width: auto;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li.active, #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3393b5;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li.active, .no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li:hover{
    background-position: 0px 50%;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li:hover ul, .no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li:focus ul {
    left: -5px;
}
```

and the jQuery that animates it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Fix background-position < IE8
    if ($('html').hasClass('oldie')) {
        $("ul.child li:not(.active)").each(function() {
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-25px 50%');
        });
        $("#breadcrumbs ul")
    }

    //Animate dropdown menu
    $("#breadcrumbs>ul:not(.child)>li").each(function() {
        crumbWidth = $(this).width();
        if($(this).width() > $(this).children('ul.child').width()) {
            $(this).children('ul.child').width(crumbWidth + 43);
        }
    });
    $("#breadcrumbs>ul:not(.child)>li").hover(
      function () {
        var raquo = "&raquo;";
        $(this).children('ul.child').hoverFlow('mouseenter', {'height': 'show'},250).children('li:not(.active)').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).hoverFlow('mouseenter', {textIndent: 10, backgroundPosition: '-0px 50%'}, 250);
            },
            function () {
                $(this).hoverFlow('mouseleave', {textIndent: 0, backgroundPosition: '-25px 50%'}, 250);
            }
        );
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).children('ul.child').hoverFlow('mouseleave', {'height': 'hide'}, 250).children('li').unbind();
      }
    );
});
```

The live site: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/

Thanks guys.

Comment: +1 for the concept of beating Microsoft up down a dark alley if nothing else...

Comment: This website is for Q&A, not rants.

Comment: Make sure the misbehaving `<li>`s don't have the `float: left` you're applying to the parent's `<li>`s. Also, try applying a `display: block`, just in case.

Comment: What the itend for $("#breadcrumbs ul") in the first if? Just left over? For the width issue you should be able to fix the lis by just grabbing the ul width and setting it up for the li and I suspect it might help the animation if all child have the same width.

Comment: @NADH they have both 'float: none' and 'display: block' yet IE7 still disregards them. :(

Comment: @gillesc unfortunately I need the site to function without the use of javascript, javascript is just a beautifier. I don't understand your question about `$("#breadcrumbs ul")`

Comment: @GeorgeReith, how about giving a fixed width to the `<li>`s ?

Comment: @NADH They are way too variable, some are really long and some really short. =/ (they change depending on which page you are on)

Comment: @GeorgeReith, you can use Javascript to set the width dynamically.

Comment: $("#breadcrumbs ul") does nothing but do a CSS query and return a jQuery instance with those elements. However it is no assigned to anything and no function after so it doesn't do anything but a query (I guess it would create a cache inside jQuery if that was the intend). And fair enough about not using Javascript, unobstructive is always best. Have you tried width:inherit to see if the li would inherit the ul width. I would try * { zoom:1; } also, I know you have it set here and there but sometimes it need to be set in the less expected places.

Comment: @gillesc ah yes it is left over, unfortunately setting `*{zoom:1;}` and `width:inherit` made no difference :(

Comment: Was a bit of a long shot, no IE on this system so can try anything, will see more later if nobody fixed it yet

Comment: You are using jQuery to animate your menu when you show it. Why then do you have a problem setting the width of the li's with jQuery/javascript? If jQuery/JavaScript is disabled you won't see the dropdown anyway.

Comment: @KevinB Are you sure about that? The menus work perfectly fine without javascript. Graceful degradation my friend.

Comment: Ah, i missed that in your linked css, sorry.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for us to work with(may be worth linking in your question) http://jsfiddle.net/F6LBV/

Comment: @KevinB Thanks :), would you rather I added the rest of the code such as the grid which will make it look more realistic or will that make it more annoying to edit (more code)?

Comment: width:100% on the `#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul` seems to fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/F6LBV/3/

Comment: Adding more code will just complicate it, unless it interacts with this menu.

Comment: @KevinB That forces it to the width of the parent `li` the problem is often the parent `li` is smaller than the dropdown options thus causes clipping and text-overflow. if you have firebug or similar developer tool this is apparent on this page: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/quality/teamwork/team-meetings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width:100%` on the `#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul` seems to fix both problems. http://jsfiddle.net/F6LBV/4

tested in IE7 and Chrome so far.

Comment: I almost want to say stop fighting it and use a table, but that's such a bad thought. However, it would work.

Comment: A table... containing non-tabular data... surely not!

Comment: Sometimes that's what you have to resort to. Most degrading drop-down menus i see avoid this issue by using a set width and word wrapping.

Comment: @GeorgeReith I guess what I'm really saying is maybe what you are trying to do simply isn't possible to replicate in IE7 due to the rendering engine being used by that browser.

Comment: You are probably right, I'd rather be poopoo'd by a few web designers than sacrifice my user's experience for a bit of semantics.